# multiple jquery-ui popup boxes on the same form

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, popup, modal-dialog

I have the following in my asp page:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="FeaturedContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent">

<!--//**********************************
    // Test modal popup
    //**********************************  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Total out of range dialog
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            modal: true,
        //    autoOpen: false,
        width: 570,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

        });
    });
</script>

<!--//**********************************
    // Test modal popup 2
    //**********************************  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Total out of range dialog
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog2").dialog({
            modal: true,
            //    autoOpen: false,
            width: 570,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }

        });
    });
</script>
```

And then further down, at the very bottom of the page I have this:

```
<div id="dialog" title="ATTENTION">
    <table style="width:565px; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; ">
             <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Achtung.svg/2000px-Achtung.svg.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px" />

            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <p><center><b>This is NOT the production version of the application.</b></center>
                <p>This version is used for TRAINING or TESTING PURPOSES ONLY. If you intended to be in the production version, please close this version and access the production environment. If you have additional questions, please refer to the SOP or consult your manager.</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="dialog2" title="ATTENTION">
    <table style="width:565px; border-spacing:0px; border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr>
            <td style="width:65px; ">
             <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Achtung.svg/2000px-Achtung.svg.png" style="height: 50px; width: 50px" />
            </td>
            <td style="width: 240px">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" Height="20px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlRole_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="230px"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is, they both pop up when the page loads, but the second one (Dialog2) should only pop up when a certain button is pressed.

How do I suppress the 2nd popup from opening when the page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention it, but is there a Reason you uncomment the Option autoOpen
in your second Dialog? Setting it to false should do the Trick.

From http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen

> **autoOpen**
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Default: true
>
> If set to true, the dialog will automatically open upon initialization. If false, the dialog will stay hidden until the open() method is called.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  So dumb of me...  :o)

Answer (score 2):

In Script set `autoOpen: false,` for second dialog and define open function in first dialog,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal: true,
        //autoOpen: false,
        width: 570,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
                "open": function () {
                $('#dialog2').dialog("open");
            }
        }

    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog2").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 570,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

[See in Action](http://jsfiddle.net/yLpdLzp0/1/)

Comment: This was perfect, but I had to give the check to the first answer since it was first (and both were right).  I gave you an upvote, though.  Thanks!

Comment: yeah i know i posted second, took me sometime to create a fiddle and Thanks for +1, glad to be any help at all.